# How do I know Postgres streaming replication is working?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have set up a standby server to follow a primary Postgres server following `[this wiki page][1]`. The issue is that I am not sure the primary server is sending anything to the replica because I don't see any `walsending` and `walreciving` processes on either server when I grep the process list:

```
[primary] $ ps -ef | grep sender
[standby] $ ps -ef | grep receiver
```

My recovery.conf file looks like this:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=${MASTER_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR} port=5432 user=${REP_USER} password=${REP_PASS}'
trigger_file = '/tmp/promote_db_slave'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

I know the connection is established between the two servers because `pg_basebackup` succeeds, and when I create the trigger file, the standby server is brought up to date with the base backup. But none of the changes in the primary are sent to the standby.

EDIT: my postgresql.conf in the primary server

```
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 10
max_connections=100
checkpoint_segments = 8
wal_keep_segments = 8
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/archive/%f'
```

EDIT2:

I'm using [this guide.](https://gist.github.com/mattupstate/c6a99f7e03eff86f170e)

Comment: check `pg_stat_replication`

Comment: It comes up blank. I wonder if if my `archive_command` is the reason it's not working. I am pasing that into the post. Would appreciate your insight..

Comment: No, `pg_stat_replication` only shows streaming replication connections, and only when queried on the master. So it'd be `primary_conninfo` that'd be the issue if anything. Check the log files.

Comment: Can you please help me figure out what is wrong? I created another post for the bizarre connection problems that I'm running into: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97374/no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-replication-connection-from-host