# no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host

Tags: postgresql, replication, pg-hba.conf

([Also posted to pgsql-general](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMcqKmmibeZzPdcuEHugkM9cK0QKK9jD6ByNCtxo=xsGDx9kTw@mail.gmail.com))

I have been configuring a slave server that needs to connect to the host. Both the master and the standby servers have a pg_hba.conf that looks like this:

```
# Allow anyone to connect remotely so long as they have a valid username and
# password.
host    replication     ${REP_USER}     0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    ${DB_NAME}      ${DB_USER}      0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

This should allow access from every IP address, right? Evidently, though, the standby server cannot connect using the REP_USER credentials via `primary_conninfo`

```
primary_conninfo = 'host=${MASTER_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR} port=5432 user=${REP_USER} password=${REP_PASS}'
```

I know this doesn't work because I never see in my logs:

```
LOG:  streaming replication successfully connected to primary
```

..and I cannot connect to the master server via psql either:

```
psql -h $MASTER_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -U replication
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "$SLAVE_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR", user "replication", database "replication", SSL off
```

Why? I don't get it...

Comment: Are these `${REP_USER}` etc entries literal? Or are you editing for the sake of the post?

Comment: I'm replacing them with `replication`, which is a keyword, I think...maybe I should quote it? As in `"${REP_USER}"`

Comment: I changed the replaced username to `rep` but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: So this is some kind of input into a preprocessor that then produces the real `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: yes, exactly right.

Answer (score 3):

When doing this:

```
$ psql -h $MASTER_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -U replication
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "$SLAVE_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR", user "replication", database "replication", SSL off
```

Since there's no explicit database indicated with `-d` (for example `-d postgres` ), it takes `replication` as the database, the same as the user name. However that's probably not what you want. `replication` is not supposed to be a real database, as mentioned in the doc for pg_hba.conf:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

> The value replication specifies that the record matches if a
>   replication connection is requested (note that replication connections
>   do not specify any particular database). Otherwise, this is the name
>   of a specific PostgreSQL database.

So if you expected that this line:

```
host    replication     ${REP_USER}     0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

would allow `psql` to connect with the command above, it's normal that it doesn't work, even assuming that `${REP_USER}` is actually `replication`.

As for the other line:

```
host    ${DB_NAME}      ${DB_USER}      0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

not knowing what are the real values for `${DB_NAME}` and `${DB_USER}` it's not really possible to comment on it.

If the real problem is the replication not happening, I don't think `psql` is very useful to test this since `psql` must connect to a specific database before doing anything useful, whereas the replication process must not and does not.

Comment: I can connect to the `DB_NAME` with `psql`. That I noticed. But for the other one, shouldn't the error say something about not having a database by that name?? Why does it complain about `pg_hba.conf` entry?

Comment: Incidentally, I also tried adding `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` to see if that would make any difference, but it didn't.

Comment: @picardo: the error is understandable, because the `pg_hba.conf` filter comes first. If the `user/db/host/origin` combination doesn't match any line in pg_hba, it doesn't even check if the user and db exist. And if it did report it in the error message, that would be leaking information to unauthorized clients and wrong as such.